# Random number generator always generates the same number in a for loop?

Tags: java, random

This is my code, the output I'm keep getting is:

```
Number is:54
Number is:54
.
.
.
Number is:54
Number is:54
Number is:54
Number is:54
Process completed.
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class random {

    private static Random call = new Random();
    private static int numb = call.nextInt(75) + 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            if (numb < 16) {
                System.out.println("Number is:" + numb);
            } else if (numb < 31 && numb > 15) {
                System.out.println("Number is:" + numb);
            } else if (numb < 46 && numb > 30) {
                System.out.println("Number is:" + numb);
            } else if (numb < 61 && numb > 45) {
                System.out.println("Number is:" + numb);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Number is:" + numb);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Is there a way to fix the code WITHOUT putting

```
private static Random call = new Random();
private static int numb = call.nextInt(75) + 1;
```

in the main code? (means WITHOUT creating `new Random()` and the number it generated in the main code)

The reason is that I also need to pass int "numb" into other classes and they have to be the same parameter.  if I just stick
    numb = call.nextInt(75) + 1;
in the for loop in the main class. Sure it will work, but the parameter of "numb" will be different in every single class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just stick:

```
numb = call.nextInt(75) + 1;
```

In to your for loop. It'll reuse the static Random you already created.

Comment: Just be careful to use a different Random instance per thread or you might find your random numbers to be...less so.

Comment: @sirbrialliance  . I see,thanks. but I also need "numb" for other classes I created, and it has to be the same number as the "numb" in the main class, if I add numb = call.nextInt(75) + 1; In to the for loop in the main class, the two"numb" will be different, how do I make them the same?

Comment: @Wil Hartung  thanks for your help but what should I do if i need numb value for other class?